# GitHttpClient.GetItemsAsync thows an exception while downloading a zip file

Tags: c#, devops

I am doing something like below to download a `zip file` from `Devops server` using `gitclient`.

```
  Stream res = ghc.GetItemZipAsync(project.Name, repo.Id, componentPath, 
   versionDescriptor:ItemVersion, resolveLfs:true).Result;
   using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(string.Format(@"D:\a\1.zip"), FileMode.Create, 
    FileAccess.Write))
    {
        res.CopyTo(fs);
        res.Close();
    }
```

While coping the stream i am getting an exception.

> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport
> connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote
> host.

Any suggestions?

Comment: `GetItemZipAsync` is not a member of the .NET Framework nor .NET Core. Please tell us more about this method.

Comment: None of the code you've posted has anything to do with `HttpClient` nor `git`.